# What is the difference between model setup, model configuration, and model customization?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, sequence-modeling

In the context of research papers related to deep learning models, the authors usually mention these terms in the experiment section when they are talking about the model: **configuration**, **setup**. For example: [Akbik et al. 2018](https://aclanthology.org/C18-1139.pdf).

For example:

1. "We utilize the BiLSTM-CRF sequence labeling architecture proposed by Huang et. al (2015) in all **configurations** of our comparative evaluation."
2. "Baselines. We also evaluate **setups** that involve only previous word embeddings."

What is the difference between the terms? Is the model architecture the same with different hyperparameters?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using the search tool of my browser, I cannot find any of those terms in the paper that you're mentioning, so maybe you should explain more in detail in which section and/or page those terms can be found.

Comment: @nbro could you check the question now? I added two examples